# Is there a way to put interactive programs in your posts?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Like Wolfram Demonstrations, a Java-Applet, 3-D function grapher, etc. It would be cool if one could do that.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? I am asking a fairly simple question. Yes or no. If no, why? Maybe because one could just easily provide a link and does it not slow the site down.

Comment: chess.SE currently supports a [PGN viewer](http://meta.chess.stackexchange.com/q/176), so this is not without the realm of possibility. I'm not exactly certain what steps we would have to go through to add support to additional programs; this is something the SE devs would have to do, so discussions with the SE folks would be a must. I would imagine that a strong case (beyond "it would be cool") would have to be made for them, however.

Comment: Do you have an example of code or program which would be interesting if it was interactive?

Comment: There are so many interesting ones on http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/index.html. You need to install the CDF player first. Its free !

Comment: @Panda Bear: On the meta site, votes simply indicate agreement. Downvotes simply mean that the person didn't agree with the premise of the question.

Answer (score 7):

PLEASE DO NOT DO THIS.

Yes, I am shouting.

Embedded interactive programs will usually make a distraction.  Instead, provide a link elsewhere and put your interactive program there.

Many discussion sites even disallow embedded videos, instead requiring links only.  For the same (or similar) reasons.

Answer (score 3):

There are many issues need to be addressed before this can ever happen and should be allowed.

- Allowing arbitrary interactive gadgets on this site has serious security concerns.
  How can we stop anyone from putting something malicious here?
- There is also the issue of hosting. If a gadget need an external site to
  host.
  How can we sure the other site won't shut down or won't reorganize their URL tree?
  This is the same issue why MSE need an account on imgur to host images posted here.
- If one only allow a small number of selected gadgets and there are dedicated sites for hosting the corresponding materials.

  - Where do MSE get the manpower to manage/monitor them?
  - How to we sure everyone using this site can access them seamlessly?

    Taking wolfram demonstrations as an example. If it is something that need an extra player to view, does everyone willing to install the player? I even disable Java on my browser!
  - What is the extra benefit of embedding interactive gadgets on answers here compared to just a link to a dedicated site? Does the benefit clearly offset other issues???

Despite these concerns, it will be great if we can embed some interactive gadgets to answers on MSE. The first thing come to mind is *GeoGebra*. However I won't put too much hope for this ever to happen.